# Powershell: cannot hide 'Access is denied' error on 'Remove-Item'

Tags: powershell, exception, error-handling

I would like to keep a `Remove-Item` instruction quiet, exception or not. I'm running below command in a script to delete a certificate:

```
Remove-Item $store\$thumbprint
```

If I run the script as local Admin, fine... it keeps quiet and the file is deleted.
If however I run it as unpriviledged user, I get an 'Access in denied' error as expected, but I would like to keep this quiet in any case.

I've tried the following:

```
$output = (Remove-Item $store\$thumbprint)
# or...
try{Remove-Item $store\$thumbprint} catch{}
# or...
Remove-Item $store\$thumbprint -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

But I always get the error/exception
 displayed on the console.

Comment: `try{Remove-Item $store\$thumbprint -ErrorAction Stop} catch{$null = $_}` should work…

Comment: NB This suggestion will work unless `-Path` is a pattern. If it is a pattern and it matches 2+ items then "remaining" items may stay not removed after this exception.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful inputs. @JosefZ, you can write your solution as answer; it works for me (path is unique in my case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a *non-terminating error* is generated by `Remove-Item` and it adds an error to the `$Error` variable without throwing an exception. To see what Windows PowerShell will do when a non-terminating error arises, look at the value of the [`$ErrorActionPreference` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7#erroractionpreference) (its default value is `Continue`).

The `Access to the path '…' is denied` is an example of such a non-terminating error so you can use `ErrorAction` parameter which overrides the value of the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable *for the current command*:

```
Remove-Item $store\$thumbprint -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

On the other side, `$ErrorActionPreference` and the `ErrorAction` parameter don't affect how PowerShell responds to *terminating errors* that stop cmdlet processing. So if we are not sure whether an error is terminating or not then it's safe to handle any error the [`Try-Catch-Finally`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally) blocks using `-ErrorAction Stop` as follows:

```
try {
    Remove-Item $store\$thumbprint -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    ### A Catch block can include commands for tracking the error
    ###         or for recovering the expected flow of the script
}
```